# Ubuntu 17.10 fails to boot with AMD graphics card

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics, 17.10

I have been running 17.04 with the amdgpu driver. After upgrading to 17.10, it boots to a deep purple (blank) screen. I have whole disk encryption, so it would normally show a password prompt at this point.

The graphics card is Radeon R9 290X.

When resetting the computer, it boots to the GRUB menu, and I've tried different options:

- Kernel 4.10.0-37 works, but stops before the boot process finishes (Starting GNOME). No graphics or login prompt.
- Kernel 4.13.0-16 in recovery mode takes me to the recovery menu.

  - Resume:  Prompts for a password for my drives. <s>It times out before I can enter all the passwords*, and it takes me back to the recovery menu. Resume again gives a blank screen.</s> If I first drop to root shell and do systemctl start dev-mapper-pool, then enter passwords, then exit the shell and choose resume, I can get to a basic desktop with low graphics. I can log in,etc,. This is a huge improvement for me!
  - failsafeX: Boots to the oh so familiar low graphics screen, but none of the options help me.
  - root shell: This works. I can also remount read-write. I uninstalled some AMDGPU-PRO packages I had for OpenCL support, but it doesn't make a difference.

I have got this purple screen before, but it's usually fixed in a matter of uninstalling some AMD driver I've tried. Now, I can't see what to do..

*I have the same PW on all drives, and normally it only prompts once for the PW, now it asks for each drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall radeon using the command

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

It worked for me. Then type

```
reboot
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to check this out, and thanks for sharing. It works to bring me graphics. After this, I can even install amdgpu-pro 17.40 again with the --compute, as in this guide https://math.dartmouth.edu/~sarunas/amdgpu.html . I'll mark this as a solution since everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with Debian and my R5/230 adapter; in this case the DVI adapter was not recognised, it only accepted VGA @ 1266 instead of DVI  @ 1920

This link brought me to the right place on the AMD support website
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD and 
http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Also maybe interesting for you https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/radeon/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try to get the AMDGPU-PRO installed again. I used to have some AMDGPU-PRO components on 17.04 thanks to this page https://math.dartmouth.edu/~sarunas/amdgpu.html . I am using a Displayport to HDMI 2.0 dongle, but I also tried with a DVI monitor. Don't think I have a VGA out.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was this line

```
blacklist radeon
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf`. This was probably done by me, but not 100% sure.

Starting from live USB worked right away, and I could also boot when I removed the blacklist command. However, it used the `radeon` driver, not the `amdgpu` driver. Both drivers were loaded.

This link showed how to start with `amdgpu` driver: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-kernel-4-13-doesnt-boot-with-amdgpu/30770/13 . Adding this to the kernel command line:

```
radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1
```

The GUI didn't work for me when using this command line, except for the password prompt and console at boot. OpenCL works, so I choose to use this for now.